# Dynamically adding pages in JQM - ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, dynamic, cordova

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005069/dynamically-adding-a-page-in-jquery-mobile-not-working) I tried adding pages dynamically to my Phonegap app (build with Jquery Mobile). First I succeed, but when I replace the javascript files with a more up to date versions (/jquery-1.8.2.min.js & jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js) it fails.

Secondly I would like to know what's the best way to integrate ajax calls into this dynamic page making. I tried, but again failed. Btw, the link created is called in el.link and obviously the div overzicht is called in the body of the document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/z33.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: 'http://mllsdemode.be/Ex-cache/expo1.php',
success: function(json) {
var $overzicht = $("#overzicht");
$overzicht.empty();
$.each(json, function(i, el) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    $('body').append('<div id="kunstenaars?id='+i+'" data-role="page"><div data-role="header"><h2>' + el.naam + '</h2></div><div data-role="content">' + el.pagina + '</div></div>').trigger('create');
    $overzicht.append("<a href=" + el.link + " data-ajax='false'><img src=" + el.img + "><div class='desc'>" + el.naam + "</div></a>");
});
},
error: function() { alert("Error reading jsonP file"); }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://roughlybrilliant.com/jsrender_json_apis_and_jquery_mobile) out, jsrender is a good solution